# Using execSync inside promise holds up the async code

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, child-process

I am writing a nodejs script to process (convert to PDF from various formats) large amount of files on regular basis. The script reads all files in the folder, splits them into even sized arrays and then is supposed to run a command line converter asynchronously on each of the arrays. Everything works fine except for the node waiting for the promise to return before continuing with the for loop. The code uses a test command for copying files instead of conversion because it's simpler for testing. Instead of running 5 simultaneous copy tasks it runs one after the other. I am using array of promises so I can call `Promises.all()`when all promises return. What am I missing that this is not working as it should?

```
let processCount = 5;
let promisesArray = [];
for (let processNo = 0; processNo < processCount; processNo++) {
  promisesArray[processNo] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let fileList = splitArrays[processNo];
    for (let file = 0; file < fileList.length; file++) {
      let command = `Copy "${fileList[file][0]}"  "${fileList[file][1]}"`;
      execSync(command);
    }
    resolve(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Using promises doesn't make a synchronous function asynchronous, it just holds off the blocking call until the next tick.

Comment: Thank you, that was a piece of information I was missing. I changed the code and found out that I still cannot run multiple instances of exec at the same time using this method. Research continues.

Comment: `require('util').promisify(exec)` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`execSync()` by definition blocks the event loop until the child process is done. You'll have to use `exec()` instead. The third param of `exec()` is callback function which will be called when your child process exits.